# MySQL 200% CPU Usage

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, java, hibernate

in my server MySQL taking more than 200% CPU usage. I'm running java war file in tomcat server that uses hibernate JPA to perform MySQL operation I did slowSQLQuerylogs also but there is nothing that taking more than 2 seconds but a number of queries getting performed are high because of spring-boot JPA.

```
OS:  Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

H/W specification like: 
memory: 16GB 
Architecture: x86_64 
CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit 
Byte Order: Little Endian 
CPU(s): 4 
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3 
Thread(s) per core: 1 
Core(s) per socket: 4 
Socket(s): 1 
NUMA node(s): 1 
Vendor ID: GenuineIntel 
CPU family: 6 
Model: 79 
Model name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2686 v4 @ 2.30GHz 
CPU MHz: 2300.033
```

mysqld.cnf file

```
key_buffer_size     = 128M
```

max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
max_connections        = 500
query_cache_limit   = 8M
query_cache_size        = 16M
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size     = 100M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100

when I run top command in ubuntu it showing me MySQL using more than 200% CPU usage sometimes.

```
> top

23:19:47 up 4:42, 1 user, load average: 0.86, 0.86, 0.83 Tasks: 167 total, 1 running, 116 sleeping, 0 stopped, 0 zombie %Cpu(s): 45.9 us, 4.8 sy, 0.0 ni, 47.5 id, 0.6 wa, 0.0 hi, 0.8 si, 0.4 st KiB Mem : 16424600 total, 4822956 free, 4830684 used, 6770960 buff/cache KiB Swap: 0 total, 0 free, 0 used. 11290580 avail Mem

PID   USER   PR  NI  VIRT     RES     SHR   S  %CPU   %MEM  TIME+     COMMAND
8675  mysql  20  0   3262732  856304  16244 S  162.8  5.2   74:18.57  mysqld
```

MySQL performance tuning giving me this results

```
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
Please enter your MySQL administrative login: perimetrix
Please enter your MySQL administrative password: [OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Log file: /database/mysql/mypm-aws.err(0B)
[!!] Log file /database/mysql/mypm-aws.err doesn't exist
[!!] Log file /database/mysql/mypm-aws.err isn't readable.

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MYISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 8.0G (Tables: 1130)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- Analysis Performance Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF
[OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[!!] failed to execute: SELECT CONCAT(user, '@', host) FROM mysql.user WHERE (IF(plugin='mysql_native_password', authentication_string, password) = '' OR IF(plugin='mysql_native_password', authentication_string, password) IS NULL) AND plugin NOT IN ('unix_socket', 'win_socket', 'auth_pam_compat')
[!!] FAIL Execute SQL / return code: 256
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[--] Bug #80860 MySQL 5.7: Avoid testing password when validate_password is activated

-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined

-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 1d 2h 21m 0s (103M q [1K qps], 10K conn, TX: 959G, RX: 285G)
[--] Reads / Writes: 99% / 1%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 15.7G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 8.7G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 8.2G global + 1.1M per thread (500 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 72B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 8.4G (53.51% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 8.7G (55.48% of installed RAM)
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/103M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 40% (202/500)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.06%  (7/10980)
[!!] name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection and can reduce performance
[!!] Query cache may be disabled by default due to mutex contention.
[!!] Query cache efficiency: 0.0% (0 cached / 101M selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 187K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 53751600
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 0% (108 on disk / 70K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 98% (202 created / 10K connections)
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 2% (2K open / 83K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (0/5K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (237 immediate / 237 locks)

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Memory used by P_S: 72B
[--] Sys schema is installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is disabled.

-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 18.2% (24M used / 134M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 128.0M/43.0K
[OK] Read Key buffer hit rate: 96.5% (258 cached / 9 reads)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 8.0G/8.0G
[!!] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size (1.171875 %): 48.0M * 2/8.0G should be equal to 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 8
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk : 64 for 8 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 100.00% (13946932499 hits/ 13947178305 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 30.94% (117771 hits/ 380652 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 262881 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is disabled.

-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: ROW
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: Not Activated
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: Not Activated
[--] This is a standalone server

-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
    Increase table_open_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
    Read this before increasing table_open_cache over 64:
    Read this before increasing for MariaDB https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/optimizing-table_open_cache/
    This is MyISAM only table_cache scalability problem, InnoDB not affected.
    See more details here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=49177
    This bug already fixed in MySQL 5.7.9 and newer MySQL versions.
    Beware that open_files_limit (5000) variable
    should be greater than table_open_cache (2000)
    Before changing innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group read this:
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_size (=0)
    query_cache_type (=0)
    query_cache_limit (> 8M, or use smaller result sets)
    join_buffer_size (> 256.0K, or always use indexes with JOINs)
    table_open_cache (> 2000)
    innodb_buffer_pool_size (>= 8.0G) if possible.
    innodb_log_file_size should be (=1G) if possible, so InnoDB total log files size equals to 25% of buffer pool size.
```

I'm not able to find what causes the problem.

Comment: High CPU ==> Slow query ==> missing index and/or poorly written query.  Get started here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

Comment: Please post your SLOW QUERY LOG and after 24 hours of uptime ADD to your post a new complete report from MySQLTuner.pl for analysis.

Comment: Could you post TEXT results of A) SELECT @@version: B) SELECT @@log_output; C) SELECT @@thread_cache_size;  ?  D) Which AWS platform are you using?  EC2, Aurora, RDS or another?  E) Which  model?  Will allow us to determine RAM size, CPU's available.  Thanks

Comment: 200% use when you have 4 CPU's = 50% effective busy.  Not a problem unless is stays there 24/7.

Answer (score 0):

As we faced a problem like this a broken process was still active. After a restart of the database instance the high cpu usage has gone.

Comment: thanks for replay, I restarted MySQL so many times but it does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not able to find what causes the problem

mysqltuner.pl has already given you a list of issues.

The reverse DNS lookup is howler and your innodb buffer pool is tiny (but the pool size is not contributing to your high CPU). Hibernate and performance never appear in the same sentence (unless accompanied by "bad") - but there's probably still scope for improvement there around the JDBC pool management. But you didn't tell us how that is configured.

I suspect that the DB is lacking a lot of required indexes. The best way to get the data for this is to set the slow_query threshold to 0 - but this will generate a LOT of disk I/O (so best to do it temporarily) then have a look at what queries your DBMS is speding most of its time on. Use mysqldumpslow to crunch the logs.

Answer (score -1):

Suggestions to consider for your AWS Parameters Group (my.cnf [mysqld] section)

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8G  # from 128M to use half of your RAM for data/index storage
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8  # from 1 to reduce mutex contention
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for function
```

Disclaimer: I am the content author of website mentioned in my profile, Network profile where we have FREE Utility Scripts downloadable to improve performance and other services.

Comment: thanks for replay Wilson Hauck, I updated MySqlTuner.pl

Comment: @kiritsardhara Is there a REASON you have not applied any of these suggestions?

Comment: no, I applied whatever changes you suggested but I'm waiting for 24 hrs to generate MySQL tuner report again. suggestions you suggested is working but not much MySQL still using 190% some times. I updated question pls, review it

Comment: @kiritSardhara Please also post TEXT results of SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; which should include any rogue, still running process.

Comment: I created a post in pastebin.com hear's a link: https://pastebin.com/tKh88tDg

Comment: @KiritSardhara Review your SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST to see that 200 processes are Sleeping.  It looks like there are 9 processes for each customer sleeping.  Could you post the code that does your CONNECT, processing, CLOSE for review?  It appears the CLOSE function is missing.  In your config make your thread_cache_size=100, read_buffer_size=512K, read_rnd_buffer_size=128K to improve performance.

Comment: @KiritSardhara    What is your current situation?  We still can not see code that does your CONNECT, processing, CLOSE.  It appears the CLOSE function is missing when reviewing the SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST output you provided.

Comment: @KiritSardhara Do you have access to Skype TALK?  In English?  Would be a better communication method.  View my profile, Network profile, for downloadable FREE Utility Scripts, tips, contact info.